# Testing a single package skips parametrized tests in TestNG

Tags: java, maven, parameters, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

## Overall description

I have a simple Maven project with a parameterized TestNG test. The parameter is specified through a suite XML file. When I run tests for the whole project, the suite XML file is read, parameter is used and the parameterized test is executed. However, when I attempt to test a single package only, then the suite XML file is not used apparently and the test is skipped with a complaint such as "Parameter '...' is required by @Test on method ... but has not been marked @Optional or defined". The question is how to run individual tests and test packages with parameters.

For more details see below.

### Testing the whole project

This works as expected. Two test methods are executed. One test method is parameterless, other is parameterized and the parameter value is taken from the suite XML file. This is a equivalent of Run\Test project in NetBeans.

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestNGDemo>"c:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin\mvn" test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestNGDemo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ TestNGDemo ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ TestNGDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ TestNGDemo ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestNGDemo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TestNGDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ TestNGDemo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
testGetChangedString
getTrue
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.844 s - in TestSuite
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.702s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 06 23:42:20 ACST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestNGDemo>
```

### Testing a single package

In this case only one test method runs, the parameterless one. The parameterized test method is skipped. This is a equivalent of right-clicking a package in NetBeans and selecting "Test package".

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestNGDemo>"c:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin\mvn" test -Dtest=com.endersoft.testngdemo.**.*
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestNGDemo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ TestNGDemo ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ TestNGDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ TestNGDemo ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestNGDemo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TestNGDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ TestNGDemo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.endersoft.testngdemo.SimpleClassNGTest
getTrue
[WARNING] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 2.422 s - in com.endersoft.testngdemo.SimpleClassNGTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[WARNING] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.268s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 06 23:47:28 ACST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Project source

The zipped project source can be downloaded from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AipMldO16hz3uDDyOEdYCrp60_sx) (very small)

Answer (score 0):

You need separate XML files for separate package. When running TestNG with package as parameter, TestNG is not automatically aware about the XML file, like it doesn't exist. 
So you have multiple options, specify the parameters in properties file, or hardcode them, or create separate XML files for every package that you can then pass as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate on how to specify an XML file for a package? E.g. what I want to do is to run a single test file or a single test for a package from NetBeans IDE and have an XML file specified for this particular run.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to run separate package only for testing purposes on local computer. So the easiest way is to create new XML file with the following content:

  `<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
      <test name="Regression1"   >
        <packages>
          <package name="test.sample" />
       </packages>
     </test>
    </suite>`

Now instead of using the global XML file, run this XML file which you can edit for running different packages with different parameters.